# Update private app in Play Store using Azure Pipelines

Tags: google-play, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a private Android application uploaded to the Play Store using the Google Play Custom App Publishing API (https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/publish).

The app was published by an admin from an EMM console, but I would like to automatize the app updates and use Azure Pipelines for this purpose - is there any example or documentation how to do this?

As far as I know the update is nothing more but sending a file (APK) to a server, so I think I can use an Azure task, e.g. cURL upload files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/curl-upload-files?view=azure-devops), but I wasn't able to find the destination URL.

Answer (score 0):

> Update private app in Play Store using Azure Pipelines

Azure devops support [Google Play](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) extension.This extension contains a set of deployment tasks which allow you to automate the release, promotion and rollout of app updates to the Google Play store from your CI environment.

In order to automate the release of app updates to the Google Play store, you need to have manually released at least one version through the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/). Additionally, you need to create a service account that is authorized to manage your app(s) releases on your behalf and can be used to authenticate "headlessly" from your VSTS build/release definitions. If you haven't already done so, please follow the steps in **Prerequisites** to create a service account.

Once you have created or retrieved credentials for you Google Play service account, then perform the following steps to automate releasing updates from a VSTS build or release definition:

- Install the Google Play extension from the [VSTS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-vsclient.google-play)
- Go to your Visual Studio Team Services or TFS project, click on the
  **Build** tab, and create a new build definition (the "+" icon) that is
  hooked up to your project's appropriate source repo
- Click **Add build step...** and select the neccessary tasks to generate
  your release assets (e.g. **Gulp, Cordova Build**)
- Click **Add build step...** and select **Google Play - Release** from the
  **Deploy** category
- Configure the **Google Play - Release** task with the JSON private key
  file created above, the generated APK file, and the desired release
  track.
- Click the **Queue Build** button or push a change to your configured
  repo in order to run the newly defined build pipeline
- Your app changes will now be automatically published to the Google
  Play store!

**Google Play - Release**: Allows you to release an update to your app on Google Play

- **Update APK(s)** (Boolean, Optional) - By default, the task will update the specified binary APK file(s) on your app release. By
  unselecting this option you can update metadata keeping the APKs
  untouched. Default value is true.

[image]

The Google Play extension page gives detailed instructions, you can refer to it for details.

Comment: Is this going to work with a private application uploaded with the Google Play Custom App Publishing API?